# when i reload apache I get this error

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I have this error when I get status of service apache2.

> apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
>      Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
>     Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
>              └─apache2-systemd.conf
>      Active: inactive (dead) since ج 2018-02-23 15:31:18 WET; 1min 23s ago
>        Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
>     Process: 4329 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
>     Process: 4310 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE

Comment: Please read the help section on asking a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Check if all folders for apache are created. Like "logs" and other. Same for your sites check if you specified folder for logs and if it is actually created.